# YA graphic novel about airships

Tags: story-identification, steampunk

It was a series of graphic novels that I got from the library around early 2010s in North America (and I remember the art quality matching that time frame). I believe it was coloured but cannot be sure. It was definitely aimed at teenagers.

The main character was a guy with some sort of creature as a pet (at the very least it was not any common animal). I believe it was closer to some sort of yellow slithering creature. The main character was a guy, with another important character being a romantic love interest for him.

The setting was definitely steampunk, I remember at least one scene taking place on an airship and I believe airships were heavily involved. I may be completely making this up but I believe the romantic interests father was some sort of admiral of the air fleet and there was a war against another steampunk empire for resources.

Comment: This sounds a lot like the *Leviathan* series by Scott Westerfield. It's a book series, but it has a very similar context and setting.

Comment: @regionalsky Good guess but unfortunately the series I'm looking for is definitely a graphic novel or manga. It had speech bubbles and everything.